# RxJava Schedulers.immediate() behavior while Unit Testing

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, rx-java, kotlin

I am trying to write test for my DAO object that uses reactive interface. I have a table with recipes and I want to test that when I insert data to this table, the subscriber receives list with recipes.

I am using TestSubscriber class and performing asserts on that class. My simple test look like this:

```
@Test
fun testSubscriber() {
    insertItem()
    val testSubscriber = TestSubscriber.create<List<Recipe>>()

    recipeDao
            .getRecipes()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .subscribe(testSubscriber)

    testSubscriber.assertNoErrors()
    testSubscriber.assertNoTerminalEvent()
    testSubscriber.assertNotCompleted()
    testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1)
    assertEquals(1, testSubscriber.onNextEvents[0].size)
}
```

The problem is that assertion `testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1)` fails because no item was emitted. But when I insert this line above
`testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`, the test is successful. My observable does not emit terminal event and therefore the timeout is performed, but in the meantime of waiting, the onNext was called with list of recipes.

My getRecipes method:

```
fun getRecipes(): Observable<List<Recipe>> {
    return query(SELECT("*")
            .FROM(Recipe.TABLE_NAME)
            .ORDER_BY(Recipe.COL_NAME))
            .run()
            .mapToList(RecipeMapper.MAPPER)
}
```

How is that possible? I thought that when I use Schedulers.immediate(), the operation will be performed on the same thread and my TestSubscriber receives the events.  If not, how should I write this test so it succeeds? I want to test that onNext is called and I don't want to insert artificial sleep commands between.

Comment: I assume that you have some time-dependent operations in your `getRecipes` (like `delay`, `timer`, `interval` etc.) or use `observeOn` or `subscribeOn` with different Scheduler. In such case Scheduler in your test will not be applied. Could you show us your `RecipeDao`?

Comment: Hi, I edited question and added my getRecipes method. I am not modyfing the subscription or observation scheduler and i am not doing any time sensitive operations.

Comment: Method `run()` looks suspicious to me - does it return `Observable`? Or does `mapToList` return `Observable`? If so, maybe one of those methods declare their own Scheduler?

Comment: Well I solved that :) I was using library SqlBrite and it was observing query on specific scheduler. And if no scheduler was selected it used Schedulers.io(). When i switched that to Schedulers.immediate(), tests are succeeding. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see. Good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was using library SqlBrite with additional framework SqlBrite-Dao. SqlBrite is observing a query on specific `Scheduler` and when none was provided to `DaoManager` of SqlBrite-Dao, `Schedulers.io()` was used. The solution is to provide scheduler to `DaoManager.Builder` or apply RxJavaPlugins and return `Schedulers.immediate()` as all `Schedulers`.